# Updating column only when value is non-empty

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Consider the following PL/pgSQL procedure:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _notes VARCHAR := 'something';
    _id BIGINT := 11683;
BEGIN
    update person set notes = CASE WHEN LENGTH(_notes) = 0 THEN notes ELSE _notes END WHERE id = _id;
END
$$
```

The goal is to update **notes** column only when **_notes** variable is not an empty string. This example works, but **_notes** variable is used twice in UPDATE statement. I would like to know if there is a way to do it using it only once (without writing a custom database function).

The reason I need this? I am writing a Java class which automatically writes POJOs to the database. Some fields can be marked to be saved only when non-empty. As JDBC supports only positional parameters, with existing solution I would need to specify the same parameter twice, which would not be consistent with the rest of my code.

A side question: if the value **is** empty, update statement would essentially read: `UPDATE person SET notes = notes`. Is PostgreSQL smart enough not to do any actual updating in this case?

**EDIT**

Apparently, this is not possible. The only way would be to write a custom PL/pgSQL function, something along the lines of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coalesce_empty(varchar, varchar) RETURNS varchar AS $$
    SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH($1) = 0 THEN $2 ELSE $1 END;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

But that requires full control over the database.

Comment: Why don't you simply check that `notes` is not empty in Java code, and only run the `UPDATE` when this is the case?

Comment: "*Is PostgreSQL smart enough not to do any actual updating in this case*" - Postgres will do what you tell it to. If you tell it to update the column with a value it will do so.

Comment: @MickMnemonic This is a simplified example. There are other fields being updated in the same statement. I could modify the SQL when notes field is empty, but that would prevent me from using the statement in a batch.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK. But if you tell it to update a column with the value read from that same column, it is quite obvious that writing the value is unnecessary . Databases are known to do optimizations when possible, so I thought this could be one of them.

Comment: No DBMS I know (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Firebird) does something like this.

Comment: Btw: it would be more efficient to add the check to the `where` clause: `update person set notes = _notes where id = _id and _notes <> ''`

Comment: Note that Spring's NamedJdbcTemplate supports named parameters: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html. You might consider using it, as it also provides a number of other useful features.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, but I've given up on any and all JDBC utility libraries, ORM solutions and such. Few useful features, such as named parameters, are not enough to convince me to add additional dependencies and complexity to my project.